# Vaadin 14.4.2's "select" box cannot be set a second time with the setItems command

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

In Vaadin Flow 14.4.2, I am successfully able to do a setItems on a select component *the first time* it runs. However, if it runs a second time (eg as a result of a filename text field changing), I get errors. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
filename.addValueChangeListener(e -> {
           //other code (removed for SO)....
            final IntArrayList lstTrees = new IntArrayList();
            //populate lstTrees code (removed for SO)
          //  treeNum.removeAll(); //I tried this as a hack, but it too throws error
          // treeNum.clear(); //I tried this as a hack, but it too throws error
            treeNum.setItems(lstTrees); //this throws error when called the 2nd time!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            treeNum.setValue(0);
        });
```

The error is not overly useful, but here it is anywas:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.deepsearch.fe.tab2vizdb.fpsgraphicaldetails.spectratab.hslspectrachartandalts.UiSingletree.lambda$new$f28a286$1(UiSingletree.java:134)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.AbstractFieldSupport.lambda$addValueChangeListener$828eca10$1(AbstractFieldSupport.java:96)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:205)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:194)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.Component.fireEvent(Component.java:359)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentUtil.fireEvent(ComponentUtil.java:386)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.AbstractFieldSupport.setValue(AbstractFieldSupport.java:207)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.AbstractFieldSupport.setValue(AbstractFieldSupport.java:133)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:181)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.HasValue.clear(HasValue.java:179)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.select.Select.reset(Select.java:724)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.select.Select.setDataProvider(Select.java:419)
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.HasDataProvider.setItems(HasDataProvider.java:50)
    at com.deepsearch.fe.tab2vizdb.fpsgraphicaldetails.spectratab.hslspectrachartandalts.UiSingletree.lambda$new$3fab9f70$1(UiSingletree.java:128)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.AbstractFieldSupport.lambda$addValueChangeListener$828eca10$1(AbstractFieldSupport.java:96)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:205)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:194)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.Component.fireEvent(Component.java:359)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentUtil.fireEvent(ComponentUtil.java:386)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.AbstractFieldSupport.setValue(AbstractFieldSupport.java:207)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.AbstractFieldSupport.setModelValue(AbstractFieldSupport.java:167)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.AbstractField.setModelValue(AbstractField.java:225)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.AbstractSinglePropertyField.handlePropertyChange(AbstractSinglePropertyField.java:352)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.AbstractSinglePropertyField.access$200(AbstractSinglePropertyField.java:48)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.AbstractSinglePropertyField$1.propertyChange(AbstractSinglePropertyField.java:325)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementPropertyMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementPropertyMap.java:454)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementPropertyMap.fireEvent(ElementPropertyMap.java:454)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementPropertyMap.access$100(ElementPropertyMap.java:48)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementPropertyMap$PutResult.run(ElementPropertyMap.java:166)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.runMapSyncTask(ServerRpcHandler.java:395)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$0(ServerRpcHandler.java:389)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:389)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:317)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:89)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1545)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1701)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:78)
    at com.deepsearch.fe.web.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1701)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
```

FYI: My lstTrees array is not null; so the null pointer exception refers to some Vaadin component. Also, although I don't think this is relevant, I used Vaadin Designer to construct the UI. FYI #2: Also, I feel like I've seen a similar error a few years ago with the "Select" component not being able to be "reset" to a new list, but when I google around, I can't find any solution to the problem. FYI #3: Just as a hack, I also tried to call the `clear()` and `removeAll()` methods of the select component, but both of them through errors too.

Comment: What's on line UiSingletree.java:134?

Comment: Thank you @MarcusHellberg  I didn't realize that UiSingletree.java:134 was pointing to my code (duh!). That solved my problem. There is NO bug in Vaadin for this issue -- it was strictly developer error.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @MarcusHellberg  I didn't realize that UiSingletree.java:134 was pointing to my code (duh!). That solved my problem. There is NO bug in Vaadin for this issue -- it was strictly developer error.